# How to download all dependencies of RPM to offline installation on SUSE 12 SP15

Tags: linux, rpm, gnu, suse, zypper

I have SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP5 and RPM which should be installed offline. How to download all dependencies of RPM to transfer them to offline machine with same OS?

I've tried downloading a desired .rpm, then install it on the SUSE 12 machine (not connected to Internet), it then asks for another package...  And the cycle repeats, it seems to be endless and reached my desperation level.

Note that I'm not too familiar with RPM-based distros (well, I was, back 22 years ago), more with DEB-based distros.

(same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68208874/how-to-download-all-dependencies-of-rpm-to-offline-instalation , hopefully this will be a better place to ask)

Addendum: I'm now trying to launch a docker image with a Suse, and then to install the desired packages from within that container (I hope to be able to catch the downloaded rpm's and copy them onto the offline machine).
Note that I'm running on a Devuan (Debian-based, without systemd) distro.

Comment: The answer you got on Stack Overflow seems pretty good, so what's wrong with it?

Comment: Well, it was first mentioned that it wasn't the good place to ask that question...
The proposed solution seemed quite "heavy": I have a low-quality Internet connection, so downloading an ISO may take a few hours if not days.
All I want is to install some simple utilities, so just accessing a repo from within a container containing a base Suse would be my preferred choice.

Comment: Does your zypper have the parameter of `--requires-pkg`?

Comment: Apparently not: `latitude:/ # zypper --requires-pkg
The flag --requires-pkg is not known.`

Comment: I'm not using SUSE, so : does it support `yum`?

Comment: I'm in a container with an opensuse, I haven't been able to find an image for the SLES 12 SP5, which I'm targeting.

Comment: There is no yum, no.  I'll try to install it with zypper.